# Multiple mounts veracrypt containers through powershell

Tags: powershell, veracrypt

I want to be able on powershell run, to mount 2 containers. I succeeded with this ps code:

```
Push-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\"
.\veracrypt /v f:\cont1 /l a /a /p mypassword /e
.\veracrypt /v f:\cont2 /l b /a /p mypassword /e
```

But this is not such good approach, beacause I turn on 2 instances of veracrypt.. can I join /v coomand for both containers through one instance of veracrypt?

Answer (score 1):

Add `/q` parameter to quit after mounting the drive.  This will mount the volume and then exit.

```
Push-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\"
.\veracrypt /v f:\cont1 /l a /a /p mypassword /e /q
.\veracrypt /v f:\cont2 /l b /a /p mypassword /e /q
```

If you want to still have instance of Veracrypt GUI remain open, add `/q` only on first veracrypt command.  If you want the Veracrypt tray icon to be visible, use `/q background` instead.  For more information, see [VeraCrypt Help on Command Line Usage](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Command%20Line%20Usage.html)